# Mvc: Create method to populate dropdown list from a class and call from controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

The code below works very well in my Index controller action
which populates a dropdownbox using database data.

I don't want to use this directly in my controller because I will be using 
the dropdown in multiple places on my page.

```
var db = new StoreManagerEntities();
        var query = db.Categories.Select(c => new
        {
            CategoryId = c.CategoryID,
            Categoryname = c.CategoryName,
            IsSelected = c.CategoryID.Equals(0)
        });

        var model = new SelectViewModel
        {
            List = query.ToList()
                        .Select(c => new SelectListItem
                        {
                            Value = c.CategoryId.ToString(),
                            Text = c.Categoryname,
                            Selected = c.IsSelected,
                        })
        };

        return View(model);
```

I want to be able to put the code in a method and call this method from my controller
Here is another class where I want the method to go.

```
public class NorthwindDataContext
{

    StoreManagerEntities myDb = new StoreManagerEntities();

    //retrieve all category objects
    public List<Category> GetCategories()
    {
        return myDb.Categories.ToList();
    }

    //populate dropdownbox
        public void PopulateDropdown()
        {
              var query = db.Categories.Select(c => new
        {
            CategoryId = c.CategoryID,
            Categoryname = c.CategoryName,
            IsSelected = c.CategoryID.Equals(0)
        });

        var model = new SelectViewModel
        {
            List = query.ToList()
                        .Select(c => new SelectListItem
                        {
                            Value = c.CategoryId.ToString(),
                            Text = c.Categoryname,
                            Selected = c.IsSelected,
                        })
        };

        }


}

  Can you please show me how I can write the method here and have it 
  return the data I need back to the controller. It will be nice if you 
  can show me how to call this from the controller as well.
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Can you please show me how I can write the method in a class and have it 
  return the data I need back to the controller. It will be nice if you 
  can show me how to call this from the controller as well.

Answer (score 0):

How about you change your `NorthwindDataContext` class like

```
public class NorthwindDataContext
    {
        StoreManagerEntities myDb = new StoreManagerEntities();    
        //retrieve all category objects
        public List<Category> GetCategories()
        {
            return myDb.Categories.ToList();
        }    
        //populate dropdownbox
        public SelectViewModel PopulateDropdown()
        {
            var query = db.Categories.Select(c => new
                {
                    CategoryId = c.CategoryID,
                    Categoryname = c.CategoryName,
                    IsSelected = c.CategoryID.Equals(0)
                });

            var model = new SelectViewModel
            {
                List = query.ToList()
                            .Select(c => new SelectListItem
                            {
                                Value = c.CategoryId.ToString(),
                                Text = c.Categoryname,
                                Selected = c.IsSelected,
                            })
            };
            return model;

        }    

    }
```

Notice the change in return type of `PopulateDropdown()` and `return model;`

And use it in the controller like:

```
var db = new NorthwindDataContext();
var model = db.PopulateDropdown();

return View(model);
```